# How to update the Assembly Version with Current Date in Jenkins Free Style for C# solution?

Tags: c#, jenkins

I need to update the current date to the Assembly Version in C# in the Jenkins Free Style Build.

```
E.G[assembly   :     AssemblyVersion("2021.09.01.00")] [assembly   :  AssemblyFileVersion("2021.09.01.00")]
The    Next    Build     should     increment     by    
[assembly   :    AssemblyVersion("2021.09.01.01")]    by    incrementing    to     01    as    the revised     version.
```

How can I increment the Assembly Version with Date and Build      combination.

Comment: Have you considered basing the increment on the number of commits on that day? That way each build should result in a unique version.

Comment: Hi gjhommerson,The date changes everyday and the First Build for the day should have todays date 2021.09.02.00.The next build should have 2021.09.02.01 and increments to 02 ,03 and so on till that day ends.The Next day it should start with 2021.09.03.00 again with increase in date and versioning should start from 00,01,02,.....Can you please guide me.

Comment: Without more information it is hard to give help. What is your current build script? What are you currently using to determine the version? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using MSBuild in Jenkins Free Style.I have tried Change Assembly  Version Builtin Plugin in Build section in Jenkins .I have configured as " Assembly Version : $BUILD_NUMBER , FileName : Path\AssemblyInfo.cs , RegexPattern : Assembly(\w*)Version\("(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)"\) , ReplacementPattern : Assembly$1Version("$2.$3.$4%s") . Error I am getting as "Build step 'Change Assembly Version' marked build as failure . Finished: FAILURE".